# Query to return all of the associated MTM elements but only if a specific one is among them

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-by, having

I have 3 tables associated like this:

```
:Manga
| id | title     | author          |
|----+-----------+-----------------|
|  1 | Initial D | Yuki Urushibara |

:Tags            :Manga_Tags_Association
| id | name   |  | tag_id | manga_id |
|----+--------|  |--------+----------|
|  1 | racing |  |      1 |        1 |
|  2 | sports |  |      2 |        1 |
|  3 | chill  |  |      3 |       23 |
                 |      1 |        5 |
```

Where the third one represents the association between manga entries and tags (so `'Initial D'` is tagged as both `'racing'` and `'sports'`

I already have queries to search and filter in different ways, but I'm struggling really hard at filtering by a tag while returning a result like this, preserving *all* of the tags associated tags:

```
| M.id | M.title   | tags                  |
|------+-----------+-----------------------|
|    1 | Initial D | racing, sports        |
|   55 | REDLINE   | sports, racing, scifi |
```

How can I do this if, let's say, I'm filtering by tags that are equal to `'racing'`? My attempts either exclude all of the tags that are not the one specified from the results, looking like this...

```
| M.id | M.title   | tags   |
|------+-----------+--------|
|    1 | Initial D | racing |
|   55 | REDLINE   | racing |
```

...or don't work at all, like the ones I've tried thinking I can check the contents of `GROUP_CONCAT` (`SELECT ..., GROUP_CONCAT(Tags.title) AS AllTags ... something something ''racing' IN AllTags;)` given it's not a table. I also couldn't get this done by doing a subquery listing all of the tags related to a `Manga.id` and checking if any of the rows contains `'racing'`, because I don't know if that's even possible (I couldn't find how). Nor using `HAVING 'racing' IN` a subquery aliased `AllTags` (same issue as before, it complains *it's not a table*).

Edit: OK I just saw some things about windows, I'm experimenting with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, aggregate and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) tags
FROM Manga m
INNER JOIN Manga_Tags_Association mta ON mta.manga_id = m.id
INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.id = mta.tag_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING MAX(t.name = 'racing') = TRUE; -- just HAVING MAX(t.name = 'racing') will also do
```

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I need, and the only part I was missing was the last line... It's gonna be the best answer, but could you explain what the `MAX` function is doing here? This looks like when people sum up booleans in languages like Python.

Comment: @MIPA the boolean expression `t.name = 'racing'` maybe either 1 (true) or 0 (false). If the max value of this expression is 1 for a particular manga id  this means that there is one related row in tags where the expression is true. If the max value is 0 this means that all related tags are not 'racing'.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: is `MAX` iterating over all of the values of `t.name` once per row, evaluating in false most of the time (like when there are 10 tags for a manga entry) but true when there's a `'racing'`? Assuming that's correct, then if the condition were `HAVING t.name = 'racing'`, what would it be doing instead? Sorry I'm asking this much, I'm trying to make sense of the documentation I'm finding.

Comment: @MIPA `HAVING t.name = 'racing'` is invalid in standard SQL (although it is allowed in SQLite) because  the HAVING clause is used to filter the results after the aggregation is done, so it must reference only aggregated columns/expressions or the columns used in the GROUP BY clause. If you try `HAVING t.name = 'racing'` you will get mostly wrong results (any correct results will be coincidental). Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kGzcFVuaPQqY7XfTGLtzVH/0

Comment: @MIPA your first assumption about MAX is correct.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, it's been really insightful.